# How to show category description in the category grid?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I was trying to show woocommerce product category description right after the category title.
[image]

I used `add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'show_woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 99);` **hook** and injected some lorem ipsum inside `show_woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description` function but it didn't display.

How do I do that?

Comment: What is the file that you used to edit the page layouts?

Answer (score -1):

I would try ***woocommerce_after_subcategory_title*** hook. Also, it is possible that your theme modifies front-end behavior, so you can try to test the code using default theme.

If it works with default theme, you need to explore available hooks in the theme.